# Add due_payment table to the existing database and alter some features

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called payment which holds records for student payment,Student details are saved in another table.

```
|payment_id  | stuid |  stu_name | recipt_no | descr   | grade | scl_fees |sec_fees | fac_fees | sport_fees | pay_comp | paymentdate | record_status | is_reverse | reverese_date_time | reverese_user | created_at | updated_at | full_amount | pay_com_month |

| 001111     | 23214 | Jhon      |2017cc12   | Nov,Dec | 4A    | 500      | 200       | 200      | 300        |200       | 1300        | 2017-12-10    | paid       |0                   |               |            |2017-12-10 |6500         | Oct
```

System is up and running without issues,Student were supposed to complete their payments within the year,as per 1300 * 12.If so System reset all the values and prepare for the next year payment,

But in real scenario,some student didn't complete the payment as they supposed.So they need to move those due payments to next year.
Unfortunately my system was designed around the above table,in order for the new year i have to move those values for a new table,
but those due payments,I am kind a lost there.any idea guys !

My Solution is to create a another table called due_payments and hold those record.Because after completing those records for the last year,The payment table has to truncate and start from the beginning.But what will happen in next years to come.
i used laravel platform

Can anyone give me a Soultion,

Thank You.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about Laravel. You want to consider asking in a database related area. Generally speaking, however, why do you need to truncate the table at all? It's not like the database won't be able to handle 1300 * 12 records. I would say just add another field to indicate the record is no longer active.

Comment: @Jason ,i will move this to database related section.as for the suggestion,can you please explain adding another field.